# URL into a ImageView

Tags: android, url, imageview, http-get

I looked all over stackoverflow and haven't found one solution for this!

```
    package com.example.sfgsfg;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.entity.BufferedHttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        try {
            URL url = new URL(
                    "http://0.tqn.com/d/webclipart/1/0/5/l/4/floral-icon-5.jpg");
            // try this url =
            // "http://0.tqn.com/d/webclipart/1/0/5/l/4/floral-icon-5.jpg"
            HttpGet httpRequest = null;

            httpRequest = new HttpGet(url.toURI());

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient
                    .execute(httpRequest);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            BufferedHttpEntity b_entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
            InputStream input = b_entity.getContent();

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }

    }

}
```

This is my latest try, and I've tried all of those below:
[Display Image(From Url) In ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996702/display-imagefrom-url-in-imageview)
[Android, Make an image at a URL equal to ImageView's image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118691/android-make-an-image-at-a-url-equal-to-imageviews-image)
[How to load an ImageView by URL in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android?lq=1)
[how to set image from url for imageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953632/how-to-set-image-from-url-for-imageview)
[Android App Display Image From URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867278/android-app-display-image-from-url)

Nothing works! And I need it without using AsyncTask! Please Help!

Comment: without asynctask u wil get anr error

Comment: @evgeny Goldin you want to download the images and want to show in image view or do you want lazy loading? Just for the clarification.

Comment: You are probably getting a Networking on main thread exception. You must not use the main thread to perform network tasks, use an AsyntTask or a Thread to load the image from the net and then just do the call to setImageBitmap on the main thread. However unless this is just as a learning exercise , you should probably use of the many excellent libraries that do all this for you *check the answer by Jorge Alfaro)

Comment: I need somehow to get a Bitmap from an URL, so later on I can set it on the ImageView. I don't mind if it uses thread, but not asynctask!
And I need it without using any external jars..

Comment: URL newurl = new URL(photo_url_str); 
mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection() .getInputStream());
profile_photo.setImageBitmap(mIcon_val);
This code looks so simple.. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use one of the following links:

http://androidexample.com/Download_Images_From_Web_And_Lazy_Load_In_ListView_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=112&aaid=134

http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/09/lazy-loading-image-download-from.html

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless/blob/master/demo/src/com/commonsware/cwac/endless/demo/EndlessAdapterCustomTaskFragment.java

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using [this](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library

Comment: I need somehow to get a Bitmap from an URL, so later on I can set it on the ImageView. I don't mind if it uses thread, but not asynctask!
And I need it without using any external jars..

Answer (score 0):

Use Glide or Picasso to fetch image from URL and set it to imageview.This two is very famous library usually used.

For Glide implement `'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'` in `build.gradle` file or in java

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(image)
                .into(imageView);
```

Or

For Picasso implement `'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'` in `build.gradle` and in java

```
Picasso.get()
  .load(url) 
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)
```